# How can I clone a specific work space to other outputs?

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager, xrandr, monitors

I am using i3-wm with Archlinux, and I nowadays are wandering that: is it possible to clone a specific work space to another output(monitor)?

It is different from `--same-as` as well as `--left-of` `--right-of` `--above` `--below`, which means that the second monitor(DP2) can only show one of my ten work spaces, my main monitor(eDP1) able to work on that work space at the mean time.

The `--same-as` option make the DP2 follow all my focus on any work space, and the other four option make eDP1 cannot show the specific work space!

So, is there any median way which make DP2 focus on one work space, without the prevention of eDP1 focusing on it?

Comment: You might want to consider dropping (at least) the /window-manager tag in favor of /i3. AFAICT this has solely to do with i3, not necessarily xorg nor xrandr per se.